# Displaying the Name of the Queried Taxonomy Term on a Term Archive Page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

*(**Moderator's note:** post was originally entitled "Taxonomy.php title")*

How can I display the *"Posts classified under:"* title for the `taxonomy.php` page? For example, this code is used in `tag.php`:

```
printf( __( 'Tag Archives: %s', 'twentyten' ), 
   '<span>' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
printf( __( 'Posts classified under: %s', 'textdomain' ), '<span>' . $tax->name . '</span>' );
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :) I can only add that WP 3.1 will have this simplified with new [`single_term_title()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14161) function.